# Help me find this game from the 2000s!

Tags: identify-this-game

It was from when I was really little, it was a stuffed white dog that I believe called out the bingo things and you had either the red or blue board and the pieces had little paw prints on them. The dog needed batteries, and (I could be wrong on this part) looked kind of like the Target dog and had blue markings on him??? My sister remembers it too but we cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Was it more a bingo type of playing or similar to https://www.amazon.co.uk/abeec-Whos-Good-Family-Game/dp/B0C3HB1DCJ (has a red/ blue board, paws on the back, a dog on the cover with blue color - it doesnt have a talking dog and is from this year but if the play style looks familiar, it might have an earlier publisher in your year range)